# set up the filter in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

please help set up the filter
http://jsfiddle.net/3pKXc/

object "news" has properties "title" and "teaser". #filter filter works with both of them.

I need the filter to work only with the "title"

ps
for example, to conduct the filter phrase "qwerty". shows that a property id = 3 left in the list. wherein "qwerty" contained in "teaser"

code:

```
<input class="filter" id="filter" type="text" name="filter" ng-model="searchText" />

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in newsVisible | filter:searchText">

        <span class="date">{{item.date}}</span>

        <span class="title">{{item.title}} - {{$index}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the template to

```
<li ng-repeat="item in newsVisible | filter: {'title': searchText} ">
```

And you need to also initialize searchText to be empty in order to show all when the query is empty.

```
$scope.searchText = "";
```